# Taking a subset of equal value and other value of column

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
> df <- data.frame(x = c('x1','x1','x2','x2','x2','x3','x3','x3'),
+                  y = c(0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0),
+                  z = c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0))
> df
   x y z
1 x1 0 1
2 x1 0 1
3 x2 1 0
4 x2 1 0
5 x2 1 0
6 x3 0 0
7 x3 0 0
8 x3 0 0
```

I would like to create a subset based on y column where it is equal to 1, keep the value of x column based on the condition and make the 1 be 0.

I have only found how I could find the first step:

```
> length(which(df$y == 1))
[1] 3
```

How could a have a final output like this:

```
x  y
x2 0
x2 0
x2 0
```

Comment: `subset(df,y==1)`

Comment: The `dplyr` library makes this remarkably easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're open to using other packages, `data.table` is another option:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[y == 1, .(x, y = 0)]

#   x y
#1: x2 0
#2: x2 0
#3: x2 0
```

Answer (score 4):

```
require(dplyr)
df %>% 
    filter(y == 1) %>% 
    select(x, y) %>% 
    mutate(y = 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 transform(subset(df[1:2],y==1),y=0)
   x y
3 x2 0
4 x2 0
5 x2 0
```